# How to specify a constraint for a column such that the value should fall among a set of values?

Tags: sql, set, constraints

I want to specify a constraint for the Grade column in my table
such that Grade='A' or 'B' or 'C'.

How do I specify this in my CREATE TABLE command?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what DBMS system you are using but this should work in Oracle or SQL Server and some MySQL storage engines:

```
ALTER TABLE <your_table> ADD CONSTRAINT Grade_Check CHECK (Grade IN ('A', 'B', 'C'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name
(
grade varchar(2),
CONSTRAINT chk_grade CHECK (grade IN ('A','B','C'))
)
```